# jQuerySpellchecker: "There was an error processing the request."

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've downloaded the jQuery Spellchecker: http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/downloads.html and extracted all files.But when I try out one of the demo files, I receive the following pop up error:

"There was an error processing the request."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you do not have PSpell on your computer, the driver doesn't exist.
Depending on the machine you are developing on, will depend on how easy it is to get working.

[Windows Option](http://www.oblius.com/blog/view.php?ID=116)

[XAMMP Option](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/enabling-pspell-in-xampp-on-windows/)

[ASpell & PSpell + Dictionaries](http://aspell.net/)

I don't use Linux, but I'm sure you can probably apt-get the driver as well.

Comment: So I've ran the command - apt-get install php5-pspell &
- apt-get install aspell on my Ubuntu shell yet the demo still brings up the same error

Comment: do you have the pspellxxx.dll in your php.ini and do you have any errors in your php log?

Comment: Hey, you were a bit late with your reply. I already found a new resource to use. But thanks!